# How to run surefire tests in parallel while forcing some to run sequentially?

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working on maven project with thousands of tests that run very slowly (takes 2h to run all the tests). So I tried to run the tests in parallel by configuring surefire plugin as follow:

```
<configuration>
  <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
  <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
  <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
  <forkCount>2C</forkCount>
  <systemPropertyVariables>
    <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
  </systemPropertyVariables>
  <parallel>suites</parallel>
  <threadCount>12</threadCount>
</configuration>
```

But then some of the tests fail in their `@Before` and `@After` methods where we initialize and clean up some resources (it seems to be related to ports conflicts).

I tried to add this annotation `@net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe` to the failing tests as described in [surefire documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) to run them sequentially and avoid conflicts. However this didn't work and these tests still fail!!!

Any pointer on how to force some surefire tests to run sequentially on same JVM process and same thread while the rest will run in parallel (potentially on different JVM processes)?

**EDIT 1**
Now, I tried to split the configuration of surefire into two: one for sequential tests and another one for parallel tests. However this approach does not seem to enhance the execution time as I still have tests that fail and it still takes 2h to run all tests.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${surefire.version}</version>
  <!-- Sequential tests -->
  <configuration>
    <includes>**/*Sequential.java</includes>
    <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <!-- Parallel tests -->
    <execution>
      <id>parallel-tests</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includes>**/*.java</includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*Sequential.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>2C</forkCount>
        <parallel>suites</parallel>
        <threadCount>12</threadCount>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: JCIP annotations are for documentation only, they have no semantic effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my final maven configuration for running the tests as wanted:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${surefire.version}</version>
      <!-- Sequential tests -->
      <configuration>
        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
          <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <!-- Default tests -->
        <execution>
          <id>default-test</id>
          <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- Parallel tests -->
        <execution>
          <id>parallel-tests</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <includes>**/*.java</includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*Sequential.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            <forkCount>2C</forkCount>
            <parallel>suites</parallel>
            <threadCount>12</threadCount>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- Sequential tests -->
        <execution>
          <id>sequential-tests</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <skip>${skip.sequential.tests}</skip>
            <includes>**/*Sequential.java</includes>
            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This works with testng, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with your "split the configuration of surefire into two" approach.

However your configuration seems to be faulty because you only have one execution defined.

Might want to try something like this (define 2 executions with their own configurations):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${surefire.version}</version>

  <executions>
     <!-- Sequential tests -->
    <execution>
      <id>sequential-tests</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includes>**/*Sequential.java</includes>
        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
    </execution>      
    <!-- Parallel tests -->
    <execution>
      <id>parallel-tests</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includes>**/*.java</includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*Sequential.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>2C</forkCount>
        <parallel>suites</parallel>
        <threadCount>12</threadCount>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Also, resuseForks=false is not really needed for sequential test executions, but will considerably slow down your Tests, I'd switch that to true if there's no good reason for false

Comment: your configuration will endup running 3 tests executions: default-test, sequential-tests and parallel-tests.

Comment: True, you have to disable the default one, but I see you've already found the solution for that

Comment: Yeah but my problem is still not fixed yet: I still see new failures and not sure weather it's really due to running them in parallel or not (I will update my solution once I made everything works perfectly).